# Int32.ParseInt throws FormatException after web post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, text-parsing

**Update**

I've found the problem, the exception came from a **2nd field** on the same form which indeed should have prompted it (because it was empty)... I was looking at an error which I thought came from trying to parse one string, when in fact it was from trying to parse another string... Sorry for wasting your time.

**Original Question**

I'm completely dumbfounded by this problem. I am basically running `int.Parse("32")` and it throws a `FormatException`. Here's the code in question:

```
private double BindGeo(string value)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"\D*(?<deg>\d+)\D*(?<min>\d+)\D*(?<sec>\d+(\.\d*))");
    Regex d = new Regex(@"(?<dir>[NSEW])");
    var numbers = r.Match(value);
    string degStr = numbers.Groups["deg"].ToString();
    string minStr = numbers.Groups["min"].ToString();
    string secStr = numbers.Groups["sec"].ToString();
    Debug.Assert(degStr == "32");
    var deg = int.Parse(degStr);
    var min = int.Parse(minStr);
    var sec = double.Parse(secStr);
    var direction = d.Match(value).Groups["dir"].ToString();
    var result = deg + (min / 60.0) + (sec / 3600.0);
    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") result = -result;
    return result;
}
```

My input string is `"32 19 17.25 N"`

The above code runs on a .NET 4 web hosting service (aspspider) on an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application (with Razor as its view engine).

Note the assersion of `degStr == "32"` is valid! Also when I take the above code and run it in a console application it works just fine. I've scoured the web for an answer, nothing...

Any ideas?

**UPDATE (stack trace)**

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9586043
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
   ParkIt.GeoModelBinder.BindGeo(String value) in C:\MyProjects\ParkIt\ParkIt\GeoBinder.cs:42
```

Line 42 is `var deg = int.Parse(degStr);` and note that the exception is in `System.Int32.Parse` (not in `System.Double` as was suggested).

Comment: Please don't destroy you own question just because you've answered it yourself. If not covered by an existing answer, then add your own answer (when you can).

Comment: Will accept my own answer in 2 days (stackoverflow enforced)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a non-question. The problem was that the exception came from a 2nd field on the same form which indeed should have prompted it (because it was empty)... I was looking at an error which I thought came from trying to parse one string, when in fact it was from trying to parse another string...

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrongly thinking that it is the following line that is throwing the exception:

```
int.Parse("32")
```

This line is unlikely to ever throw an exception.

In fact it is the following line:

```
var sec = double.Parse(secStr);
```

In this case `secStr = "17.25";`.

The reason for that is that your hosting provider uses a different culture in which the `.` is not a decimal separator.

You have the possibility to specify the culture in your web.config file:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

If you don't do that, then `auto` is used. This means that the culture could be set based on the client browser preferences (which are sent with each request using the Accept-Language HTTP header).

Another possibility is to specify the culture when parsing:

```
var sec = double.Parse(secStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This way you know for sure that `.` is the decimal separator for the invariant culture.

Comment: You are right that it is unlikely, but as the saying goes "but still they come"... That is the line that throws the exception, I've commented the other lines. Also I've tried adding the globalization line, and removing it, and setting a new culture in code on `Application_Start` and `Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: Well, I have strictly no idea why `int.Parse("32")` might fail with an invalid format exception.

Comment: I'll update my question with the stack trace to eliminate doubt.

Comment: Updated the stack trace, note that the exception is in fact in `System.Int32.Parse`...

Answer (score 2):

Testing this (via PowerShell):

```
PS [64] E:\dev #43> '32 19 17.25 N' -match "\D*(?\d+)\D*(?\d+)\D*(?\d+(\.\d*))"
True
PS [64] E:\dev #44> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
sec                            17.25
deg                            32
min                            19
1                              .25
0                              32 19 17.25
```

So the regex is working with all three named captures getting a value, all of which will parse OK (ie. it isn't something like `\d` matching something like U+0660: ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO that `Int32.Parse` doesn't handle).

***But*** you do not check that the regex actually makes a match.

Therefore I suspect that the `value` passed to the function is not the input you expect. Put a breakpoint (or logging) at the start of the function and get the actual value of `value`.

I think what is happening is:

- `Value` isn't what you think it is.
- The regex fails to match.
- The captures are empty
- `Int32.Parse("")` is throwing (just confirmed: it throws a FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format.")

*Adendum*: Just noted you comment on the assertion.

If things seem contradictory go back to basics: at least one of your assumptions is wrong eg. there could be an off by one in the exception's line number (an edit to the file before going to that line number: very easy to do).

Stepping through with a debugger in this case is by far the easiest approach. On every expression check *everything*.

If you cannot use a debugger then try and remove that restriction, if not how about IntelliTrace? Othewrwise use some kind of logging (if you app doesn't have it, add it as you'll need it in the future for things like this).

Answer (score 1):

try remove non unicode ( if any - non-visible) chars from string :

```
string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
```

### edit

also - try to see its hex values to see where it is doing exceptio n :

```
BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
```

this will show you the hex values so you can verify...

also paste its value so we can see it.